# Dynamically computing a derived field when querying MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a field in my MongoDB that needs to be generated when I query the database. It is a hash of some other fields in my database. I want the field to be dynamically generated in the database, as this provides two benefits:

- if one of the fields that the derived field depends on is updated, then I don't have to reupdate the hash as well
- I don't have to calculate the hash on my server

For example:
Lets say you have 5 fields in a car table, the car name, the car colour, the date the car was purchased, the car brand and the car hash.

I want to be able to tell whether two cars are equal simply by the car name and the car brand, but not the car colour. I want this done on the database so my web server doesn't have to loop over all records and compute the car hash. To do this, I want the car hash to be computed on the database (the hash is simply hashing the car name concatenated with the car brand). I don't want to statically define it because then any time someone changes the car name, I would also have to change the car hash.

I've tried searching but I can't quite find a way to do this in MongoDB. If anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

Edit: here are three sample records in the database:

```
{ "id" = 1, "car_name": "LX200", "car_brand": "Honda", "car_colour": "Red", "car_purchased_on": "12/01/14" }
{ "id" = 2, "car_name": "Fusion", "car_brand": "Ford", "car_colour": "Blue", "car_purchased_on": "01/01/09" }
{ "id" = 3, "car_name": "LX200", "car_brand": "Honda", "car_colour": "Green", "car_purchased_on": "25/09/93" }
```

Now I want a query to get a list of cars, grouped by the newest car **based on the hash value** of the car. This be something like: hash(car_name + car_brand).

So my query would return two records:

```
{ "id" = 1, "car_name": "LX200", "car_brand": "Honda", "car_colour": "Red", "car_purchased_on": "12/01/14" }
{ "id" = 2, "car_name": "Fusion", "car_brand": "Ford", "car_colour": "Blue", "car_purchased_on": "01/01/09" }
```

As the car with id = 3 has the same hash as the car with id = 1.

Comment: This would be such an answerable question if you just showed your document rather than making several paragraphs that don't actually explain anything. Edit your question to show a sample document and expected result.

Comment: I have edited my question to include a scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description of your use case, there isn't a need to have some server-side computed hash at all. You can use the combination of the `car_name` and `car_brand` as a key wherever you want to use the hash. For example, if you want to group cars by the "hash" of `car_brand` and `car_name`, use that as the grouping key in an aggregation:

```
db.cars.aggregate([
    { "$group" : { "_id" : { "cn" : "$car_name", "cb" : "$car_brand" } }, ... }
    ...
])
```

Note that it's not well-defined to list cars based on grouping by "hash value" of `car_name` and `car_brand` without specifying what you mean to do with the other fields that might not agree, like `car_colour`. In your example, presumably you want to return the most recently purchased car for each group, so the pipeline would look like:

```
db.cars.aggregate([
    { "$sort" : { "car_purchased_on" : -1 } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : { "cn" : "$car_name", "cb" : "$car_brand" }, "car_colour" : { "$first" : "$car_colour" }, ... } }
])
```

If you want to test if there's a car with the same hash as a car with a given `car_name` `cn` and `car_brand` `cb`, just use `find` with those values:

```
db.cars.find({ "car_name" : cn, "car_brand" : cb })
```

You could even put a unique index on `{ "car_name" : 1, "car_brand" : -1 }` to ensure that no car with the same "hash" as an already existing car can be inserted into the database.

There's no feature to compute a hash of fields dynamically on the server-side and save it to the document at update - but I'm not sure you really need that. If you do, you have to create and update the hash yourself, in your clients, as you modify the database.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I want the hash to be dynamically generated on the database. In theory I could just pass all the fields that I want grouped by and not generate the hash, but if my hash is dependent on 15+ fields it could get cumbersome. I'm wondering if there is a mechanism to group all these fields on the database side into a single field by hashing them dynamically, then using that field instead of the 15+ possible fields to group by in my query.

Comment: I think the answer already says "There is no feature to compute a hash of fields dynamically on the server-side..." so that's the answer to your question - there is no such mechanism.